# Passing variable from App.tsx to a Component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, parameters, expo, components, native

I am trying for few days to pass a parameter from my `App.tsx` to my `TabOneScreen.tsx` which is a component.

Here is my App.tsx :

```
const App = () => {
  
  const [producteurs, setSearchProducteurs] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    sqlService.initDB();
    sqlService.insertInDB();
    sqlService.search().then((data: any)=>{
      setSearchProducteurs(data)
    }).catch((error) => console.log(error));
  })

  new Map(producteurs);

  const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources();
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  if (!isLoadingComplete) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return (
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} />
        <StatusBar />
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and I tried to do a `new Map(producteurs)` which is my component.

But i don't know how to do to retrieve this parameter in my component.

I have a constructor like this :

```
class Map extends Component<any, any> {
  
  private _map: any;

  constructor(props: any){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      company_name: []
    }
  }
```

I want that my `company_name` take the value of my variable `producteurs`.

Is it possible in this way ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with react native, but i guess you do it just like in react:

1. Instead of typing "new Map(producteurs)", you are going to return this:

   ```
   <SafeAreaProvider>
    <Map company_name={producteurs}/>
    <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} />
    <StatusBar />
   </SafeAreaProvider>
   ```
2. In your Map component constructor you will need to assign the prop to the company_name:

   ```
   company_name: props.company_name || []
   ```

Comment: That's it it seems working. My only issue now is that i don't know why my app is rendering two maps, one with empty data and the other with all the markers :/ 
Thank you !